# Making an English test in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing an English testing program in Python 3. It will display a random word from my list and then ask a question about the word. There are 4 questions for the 5 words.

Do I make another list for the questions and concatenate it with the list of words?

At the moment I'm using random.choice to display a word and the enumerate function to index it (1,2,3,4,5). Can I do the same thing for the list of questions?

Can I use an if/else to display if the answer was correct?

Comment: *Do I make another list for the questions and concatenate it with the list of words?* Why would you want to do that? *Can I do the same thing for the list of questions?* Yes. *Can I use an if/else to display if the answer was correct?* Yes. If you want more help, you should probably post actual code and ask a real question.

Comment: It would be really nice if you could put a screenshot / code sample of where you are stuck. It seems like you can do whatever you have asked about.